# How to stop error being thrown by a promise when there is no catch

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I want to stop below state throwing error without using catch

```
  const p = new Promise((_, reject) => reject("Err"));
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what exactly you want

Comment: that doesn't throw an error, it creates a rejected promise - note, that code is equivalent to `const p = Promise.reject("Err");`

Comment: What do you mean by "stop error being thrown"? Are you trying to return a resolved `Promise` when a previously chained `Promise` is rejected?

Comment: Are you talking about the _"Unhandled / uncaught promise rejection"_ error you see in the console? If so, it's really just a warning letting you know your app could be more robust

Comment: oh, right I see now that at least Firefox does **show** an error - but it's not an *terminal* exception, code still continues to execute - note, in Firefox 58, the "error" is shown as `uncaught exception: Err`

Comment: Why do you not want to use `.catch()`?

Comment: simple solution, don't do that, why would you?

Comment: Op fell asleep i think so

Comment: this reminds me of the old joke .... *Patient:* "Doctor, it hurts when I do *this*" *(insert some random movement)* ... *Doctor:* "Then don't do that"

Comment: I am creating a function which is doing an http call and returning a promise. Promise is resolved when I get 200 and rejected when I get status >=400. I don't want to have catch function every time I do an http call and I want to make sure that no error is thrown when call fails, even if I don't have catch function

Comment: The error can be handled at a function at second parameter to `.then()`

Comment: @guest271314 There are ways to handle error, but can we stop error being thrown at first place?

Comment: @ImamudinNaseem - not in standard Promise in modern browsers/node- solution: use old browser/node or write your own promise library

Comment: @ImamudinNaseem Stop which error from being thrown? The code that throws the error? Or the browser source code from logging an uncaught error at `console`?

Comment: @JaromandaX Does Firefox 58 dispatch `onunhandledrejection` event?

Comment: @guest271314 the browser source code from logging an uncaught error at console

Comment: [let me research that for you](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunhandledrejection) @guest271314

Comment: @ImamudinNaseem - you wont stop this console output without catching the rejection, end of story

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. I think my requirement is against the standards of Javascript.

Comment: @ImamudinNaseem It should be possible. You can browse open source browser source code to locate where the functionality is implemented, file an issue  for a flag to disable the logging, or write the patch code to do so and build the browser yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> I am creating a function which is doing an http call and returning a promise. Promise is resolved when I get 200 and rejected when I get status >=400. I don't want to have catch function every time I do an http call and I want to make sure that no error is thrown when call fails, even if I don't have catch function

Ok, then add this to your code:

```
function makeHttpCall(options) {
    return actualHttpApi(options)
        .catch(_ => null);
}
```

Now call `makeHttpCall()` any time you want to make an HTTP request, and you won't have to catch any errors. Instead, you *will* have to check whether the result value is `null`.

Comment: Thanks. But what if I want to catch error for some calls. Do We still have suggest some solution

Comment: _"I want to catch error for some calls"_ Ok, so don't use `makeHttpCall()` when you want to catch the error?